# How do I use a computed function to specify the CSS binding within a foreach observable array

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I have a page listing multiple projects which are breeze entities in an observable array.  Using a foreach loop, I want the CSS of a label to vary depending upon the status of the project.
Because I'm using breeze, I define `var projects = ko.observableArray();` and breeze takes care of the rest, including values from a related entity (projectStatus). 
For the element I am trying to style, it exists within a `foreach: projects` list, and has binding of `data-bind="text: projectStatus().name`.  This works perfectly.  However, when I code the computed observable in the viewmodel for the CSS value, it raises an undefined error at the 3rd line (below).  Otherwise (and I've checked) the function works on the CSS if it returns a valid string:

```
    projectStatusStyle = ko.computed(function () {
    var x = "left label label-large label-info";

    var projStatus = projects().projectStatus().name();

    var style = "left label label-large label-"
    switch (projStatus) {
        case 'Live':
            x = style + "success";
            break;
        case 'Identified':
            x = style + "info";
            break;

        case 'In conversation':
            x = style + "purple";
            break;

        case 'Complete':
            x = style + "grey";
            break;
        case 'Unsuccessful':
            x = style + "yellow";
            break;

    }
    return x;
},vm);
```

So my question is, how should I refer to the projects().projectStatus().name(); observable value?

Thanks

Comment: Show the projects and projectStatus please

Comment: Second @PWKad, you'll need to show more code. Put yourself in our shoes, with just the code you've provided we can't repro the issue.

Comment: Point taken @Jeroen.  I'd have been better to phrase it as a question: Is it possible to use knockout dynamic css binding in a way that references the current observable.  I know you cannot pass a parameter to the computed function, so perhaps a custom binding handler is an option as you can get at the valueaccessor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code, but I think you have a context issue. You are defining your computed observable on your view model, but your code is kinda assuming it's defined on each object in the projects observable array. It's not, so your third line can't work. It's defined on the view model, which has no way or knowing or tracking which project in the `foreach` you're referencing.

You have a couple of options. You could change `projectStatusStyle` to a function on your view model that takes the name as a parameter:

```
vm.projectStatusStyle = function (projStatusName) {
  var x = "left label label-large label-info";

  var style = "left label label-large label-"
  switch (projStatusName()) {
    case 'Live':
        x = style + "success";
        break;
    case 'Identified':
        x = style + "info";
        break;

    case 'In conversation':
        x = style + "purple";
        break;

    case 'Complete':
        x = style + "grey";
        break;
    case 'Unsuccessful':
        x = style + "yellow";
        break;

  }
  return x;
};
```

Then you can have a binding like

```
<span data-bind="css: $root.projectStatusStyle(projectStatus().name)"/>
```

You could use `$root` or `$parent`, depending on how your view model is defined.

Honestly, I would probably just do this in your `foreach`:

```
<span class="left label label-large"
  data-bind="css: {'label-info': projectStatus().name() === 'Identified', 
  'label-success': projectStatus().name() === 'Live', 
  'label-purple': projectStatus().name() === 'In conversation', 
  'label-grey': projectStatus().name() === 'Complete', 
  'label-yellow': projectStatus().name() === 'Unsuccessful'}"/>
```

This way you're not putting style information in your JS model code.

Comment: You are exactly right @JeffB, the viewmodel had no way of knowing which project is in scope.  I couldn't get your function solution to work - I don't think knockout's dynamic css can accept a parameter, however the inline solution does work, so I'll use that - thanks.  I would've thought there would be a function-based solution, given the rules could get quite complex for other styling, and I generally try to keep my html files as simple as possible.

Comment: It should work, though I was using style instead of css in my example. Here's an example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmnwQ/. It might depend on your Knockout version, too. I think 2.2 adding the dynamic CSS functionality. In any case, glad I could help.

Comment: It works @JeffB.  So you can pass the object in the function and you don't need a ko.computed function - as this binding observes changes to the value.  Thanks so much.